# Can this code block be shortened?

Tags: c#

I have the following if statement in my code, I would like to know if there is a way to shorten it

```
if (ürün_kısakod.Text != "")
{
    komut.Parameters.Add("@kısakod", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 5).Value = Int16.Parse(ürün_kısakod.Text);
}
else
{
    komut.Parameters.Add("@kısakod", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 5).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ternary operator is an option to shorten this expression:

```
komut.Parameters.Add("@kısakod", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 5).Value =
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ürün_kısakod.Text)
    ? (object)Int16.Parse(ürün_kısakod.Text)
    : DBNull.Value
    ;
```

A better choice would be to use `TryParse` too. Usually you would report to the user the input was wrong.

Comment: Agree, I will leave the comment but without the mediocre sample. @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 2):

To avoid repetition and still be readable you can do

```
object val;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ürün_kısakod.Text)) {
    val = Int16.Parse(ürün_kısakod.Text);
} else {
    val = DBNull.Value;
}

komut.Parameters.Add("@kısakod", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 5).Value = val;
```

And since you'll likely do similar things elsewhere, make it a function (and make it generic based on the integer width if you want too):

```
object ParseInt16OrDbNull(string text) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
        return Int16.Parse(text);
    } else {
        return DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

And your code becomes just:

```
 komut.Parameters.Add("@kısakod", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 5).Value = ParseInt16OrDbNull(ürün_kısakod.Text);
```